# Conflict between standalone and rotating/sideways?

Tags: rotating, standalone, sidewaystable

I am trying to have a `sideways` table within a `standalone` class. I get an error message: `! Dimension too large.\height ->\ht \@tempboxa`.

I think it is a conflict between standalone and sideways, as I can either run *sideways in article*, or *figure in standalone* and they work fine, while *sideways in standalone* creates a problem!?

Here is the minimal code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=\maxdimen]{standalone}[2011/12/21]
%\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
%\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{cll} 
\hline \\
a & a & b \\ 
\end{tabular} 
%\end{figure}
\end{sidewaystable} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try nesting your sideways table in a minipage?

Comment: @Bernard just tried with `\begin{minipage}` and didn't help :-(

Comment: sorry but why are you trying to rotate the table in a standalone document? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Note that standalone doesn't support figures or tables or anything using  \@float.